# trying to estimate what aws will cost me based upon expected number of queries/inserts

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, estimation, amazon-rds

How can I go about determining what the cost of each mysql operation is?

It seems like when using Amazon RDS, they care about number of inputs/outputs, storage size and transfer size (both in and out).

Is the best way to go about this is to determine the average storage cost per query?

What exactly are inputs/outputs? Are inputs = the number of queries & outputs = the number of query responses?

Can I look at it in terms of like:

1 insert = (data transfer in) + (storage cost) 
1 select = (data transfer in) + (data transfer out)
1 update = (data transfer in) + ((original storage cost) - (new storage cost)) 
1 delete = (data transfer in) - (original storage cost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IO's are disk accesses.  This will vary significantly depending on database configuration and the queries you are doing.

If you have an existing server setup you can check iostat or /proc/diskstats for a rough idea on how many disk IO's you will be using.

http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/05/26/estimating-io-requests-ec2-ebs-costs